# Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.getMockSettings(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Iam developing a test case for a spring boot webservice and iam getting a error like java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.getMockSettings(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings.

Below is the webservice code , test case and the main code where the FileUtils ,AppContext(just a POJO) is used as mockBean in the test case.

Webservice code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public class ListResource {

    /* Logger **/
    private static final Logger _LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListResource.class);

    @Autowired
    private AppContext appContext;

    @Autowired
    private FileUtils fileUtils;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT_FOR_ETAG = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    private static final DateFormat eTagDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_FOR_ETAG, Locale.US);
    private static final String ACCEPT_RANGES_BYTES = "bytes";

    @RequestMapping(path = "/getlist", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
    public ResponseEntity<?> fetchGetListHead() throws IOException {
        return fetchList(true);
    }


    @RequestMapping(path = "/getlist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> fetchGetListGet() throws IOException {
        return fetchList(false);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<?> fetchList(final boolean justHead) throws IOException {
        file = fileUtils.lastZipFileWithPrefix( new File(appContext.getAppProperties().getZipDestDir()));

        try {
            byte[] readBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(readBytes);
            ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder responseBuilder = ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, ACCEPT_RANGES_BYTES)
                    .lastModified(new Date().getTime())
                    .eTag(getETag(file))
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).cachePublic().mustRevalidate())
                    .contentLength(file.length())
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE));

            return justHead ? responseBuilder.build() : responseBuilder.body(resource);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            _LOG.error("Error in gettingResource:{}", e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    private String getETag(File file) {
        String tag = "";
        if (file != null) {
            tag = eTagDateFormat.format(new Date(file.getAbsoluteFile().lastModified()));
        }
        return tag;
    }
}
```

SpringBootTest Code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ListResource.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "zip.dest.dir=src/test/resources/zip/"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ListResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private AppContext appContext;

    @MockBean
    private FileUtils fileUtils;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Value("${zip.dest.dir}")
    private String zipDestDir;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        AppProperties appProperties = new AppProperties();
        appProperties.setZipDestDir(zipDestDir);
        when(appContext.getAppProperties()).thenReturn(appProperties);

        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetList() throws Exception {    
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/resource/getlist")
                   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE).content(zipDestDir))
                   .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Below is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:gateway.properties"),
})
public class GatewayApplicationContext extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayApplicationContext.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplicationContext.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPP() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(GatewayApplicationContext.class);
    }
}
```

Dependency tree is as below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Rest :: Gateway 1.0.21-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ rest-gateway ---
[INFO] com.example:rest-gateway:war:1.0.21-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.example:rest-common:jar:1.0.12-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:jar:1.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jolokia:jolokia-core:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.pms.mobiguider:domain:jar:0.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:jar:2.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.javacrumbs:json-xml:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.atomikos:transactions-jdbc:jar:3.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atomikos:transactions-jta:jar:3.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.atomikos:transactions:jar:3.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- com.atomikos:transactions-api:jar:3.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- com.atomikos:atomikos-util:jar:3.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] |        \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:1.9.46:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:1.9.46:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:jar:1.9.46:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-portunif:jar:1.9.46:test
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-utils:jar:1.9.46:test
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-lzma:jar:1.9.46:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- com.jcabi:jcabi-http:jar:1.10.4:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jcabi:jcabi-immutable:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jcabi:jcabi-aspects:jar:0.20.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcabi:jcabi-log:jar:0.15.1:test
[INFO] |  \- com.jcabi:jcabi-manifests:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.4.2.v20170220:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.mortbay.jasper:apache-el:jar:8.0.33:provided
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.242 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-26T14:54:30+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/346M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Incompatible jars, can you post dependency tree perhaps

Comment: Dependency tree is as attached

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5 . MockUtil.getMockSettings isn't intrdocued in that version yet. Use the right version

Comment: Yes it has started working with an upgraded version of mockito-core.